# ValueError: Unknown label type: 'continuous', SVC Sklearn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

I am trying to use this library from sklearn named SVC.

However I have this error when I run my program:

```
ValueError: Unknown label type: 'continuous'
```

I do not know if there is a regressor library for Support Vector Regressor, this is the only I have found so far. Here is my code:

```
import sklearn
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from sklearn.svm import SVC

X, Y = get_data(filename)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, random_state=33)

svc = SVC()
svc.fit(X_train, y_train)

print(svc.score(X_train, y_train))
print(svc.score(X_test, y_test))
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

SVC is a classifier so will not support continous values in targets. What you need is [SVR](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVR.html). Just replace all occurences of SVC with SVR and you are good to go.

```
from sklearn.svm import SVR
svr = SVR()
svr.fit(X_train, y_train)
print(svr.score(X_train, y_train))
print(svr.score(X_test, y_test))
```